# FTP a Laravel 5.1 site to a server getting PDO error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, ftp

I have just added my files to a server using an FTP client. I then imported my .sql dump file from the database and headed over to the domain to see it in action.

I get the login page and enter the details and when I submit the form it returns the following error.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

My .env file looks like this

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_LOCALE_PHP=en_US
APP_KEY=base64:{{my-key}}

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=​​{{host-IP-double-checked}}
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE={{DB-name-double-checked}}
DB_USERNAME={{DB-user-double-checked}}
DB_PASSWORD={{DB-password-double-checked}}
```

My question is, why is this error happening and what can be done to fix it? I understand that it is just not connecting to the DB, which means that it will not run the application.

Comment: Why are you using handlebars?

Comment: So that I do not put my environment variables on the internet :)

Comment: Do you have mysql, and the php extension installed on the server?

Comment: I have MySql installed on the server as I am using it for another project. I am unsure of the PDO exstension for this. But also not sure how to install it as I am using a hosting provider. I did fear that that may be the problem.

Comment: Is the MySql server on the same machine or on an external one? If external are you sure that your application server is allowed to connect to the MySql server?

Comment: Which type of hosting are you using: dedicated, shared, managed?

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski it is a shared linux hosting package

Comment: Which hosting company?

Comment: Company called Afrihost based in South Africa